# How to activate tableau server trial version on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, tableau-api

I'd like to install Tableau Server on Ubuntu server and activate the trial on ubuntu terminal.
I downloaded `.deb` package for `Ubuntu16.04` from `https:/www.tableau.com/products/server/download/linux`.
I have already followed the installation steps. It's asking activate and register. But for right now, I want to try the trial. How can I activate the trial version and register?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue before and found the solution.
Just try this.

```
tsm licenses activate --trial
```

This will work

Comment: This adds a 14-day trial licence with 10-seats (accounts) max.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a trial version of Tableau Desktop but you can't get a trial version of the Tableau Server.